# Convert date into the format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime-format

How to convert the date (12/24/2009 12:48:00 PM) into the format dd-mm-yy?

I tried the following code:

```
DateTime.TryParse(12/24/2009 12:48:00 PM,out registereddate);
  strregdate = registereddate.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

But, the output comes as 24-48-2009. How to convert

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Month is "MM", minute is "mm". You want:

```
DateTime.TryParse(12/24/2009 12:48:00 PM,out registereddate);
  strregdate = registereddate.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
```